# Mute Telegram (maybe other apps as well) notifications programmatically

Tags: 18.04, configuration, notification, spotify, telegram

I'm trying to write a script to activate "focus mode", so there are a few apps (Telegram, Spotify, etc) whose notifications I'd like to turn off.

Is there a smart way to do this programatically?

Comment: System Settings --> Notifications manually. Use dbus to do it programmatically. Bit of a learning curve to dbus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is already introduced in [Ubuntu MATE since 19.10](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-19-10-eoan-ermine-release/) it is called "Do not disturb":

> Ubuntu MATE 19.10 includes a new **Indicator that provides a “notification center”**  We worked with the [upstream developer to add new features to indicator-notifications](https://github.com/trism/indicator-notifications) and integrate it with MATE Notifications Daemon.
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [ubuntu-mate.org](https://ubuntu-mate.org/gallery/eoan/notification-settings.png))</sub>

> We now have a notification center which also offers a **“do not disturb”**  feature. When do not disturb is enabled, notifications will not be displayed but will be captured in the notification center for review. It’s also possible to blacklist some notifications, so they are never stored by the notification center. I’ve created an icon theme for the notification center so it fits the look and feel of the default Ubuntu MATE theme. Notification hints are also fixed so any notifications supplying additional media, such as sounds or icons, now work.

You have to try porting of this idea to the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Links to check:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/indicator-notifications
- https://launchpad.net/recent-notifications
- [https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/ubuntu/recent-notifications?field.series_filter=bionic](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejconti/+archive/ubuntu/recent-notifications?field.series_filter=bionic) (looks like the PPA for the 18.04 LTS)